# Optimizing my search query through many objects

Tags: javascript, object, search, underscore.js

Snippit below, what this does is it searches through about a 100 objects and checks if my query matches with the title of a entry, one character at a time.
When entering any letter, it freezes the browser for about 5 seconds before regaining control.

Snippet:

```
results = _.filter(cmp.get('v.components'), function(item) {
            return item.componentName.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryResult) != -1;
        });
```

As a novice in Javascript i already had some issues with composing this piece of code so i'm a bit out of the field on how to improve this. I had a piece of code ready so it shows a loading screen before removing it after getting results but since the browser freezes, it would show nothing.

We are by the way limited to the use of Javascript and underscore.js so we have no access to jQuery or other libraries.

Comment: Filtering a mere 100 objects this way shouldn't cause any noticeable delay. What exactly does `cmp.get('v.components')` do?

Comment: We are using Salesforce's Lightning as framework which work with components, controllers and helpers.

What it does is getting the objects from the component script and pulls it into the helper script

Comment: Maybe assign `cmp.get('v.components')` to a variable on the line above and then step through the code. That way you can at least see if the delay is with the `cmp.get` or the `_filter`

Comment: Ah yes, will try that at once!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch from underscore to plain js, it should be close to double as fast as underscore. In addition, it's not more code. I've created a very simple basic test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g2yzyek1/1/).

The js version would look like

```
data.filter(item => item.componentName.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryResult) > -1);
```

Or its es5 equivalent

```
data.filter(function(item) { return item.componentName.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryResult) > -1; });
```

For the rest, you'll need to check for possible bottlenecks in your call to `cmp.get('v.components')`

Comment: After putting a few console.log's along the way of the script i figured that getting the data wasn't the issue but your classic method sure did improve he speed further. The issue appears to be with the graphical side. 

For each result it loads a card with a few settings on it so the user can easily search through configureable options. So i need to find a way to throttle the amount of cards it loads since loading all 100 cards at once seems to to be the thorne.

Comment: Yes, that will surely be it. Maybe have a look on something like infinite scrolling then @drVagax